# Totally unimodular <=> polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, integer-programming

Crossposting due to recommendation.

I formulated a MIP problem which I didn't expect to be unimodular. The problem is to find a minimum complete sequence in a strongly connected digraph. That is, minimize the number of edges such that connectivity is preserved, using only previously existant edges. This will be a Hamiltonian cycle if such a cycle exists.

I've verified it with AMPL/CPLEX and it at least seems to be a correct formulation. Solving the LP-relaxation, I found that it consistently provides IP-feasible solutions.

But the issue is that the minimum complete sequence problem is NP-complete. Is it even possible that I have a correct formulation given that I get a TU constraint matrix? Any ideas on how to prove that it's TU (I'm far from an expert on this thing)?

Here's the model (`option relax_integrality 1;` for the LP-relaxation)

$\begin{align}
\min \sum_{i,j} x_{ij} &\\
\sum_j x_{ij} &\geq 1 & \forall i\\ 
\sum_i x_{ji} &= \sum_i x_{ij} & \forall j \\
\sum_n y_{ij}^n &\geq 1 & \forall i,j \\
y_{ij}^1 &= x_{ij} & \forall i,j\\
x_{ij} &\leq z_{ij} & \forall i,j\\
y_{ij}^n &\leq (y_{ik}^{n-1}+x_{kj} - 1) + M(1-b_{ij}^{nk}) & \forall n \neq 1, i, j, k\\
\sum_k b_{ij}^{nk} &\geq 1 & \forall i,j,n \\
x,y,b &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$

$y^n_{ij} = 1$ iff there exists a path of length $n$ from $i$ to $j$. $z_{ij} = 1$ implies that the edge $i,j$ exists in the original graph. $b$ is a binary hack to formulate the connectivity constraint.

edit: $i,j,k,n$ all range from $1$ to $N = $ number of nodes. I realize that the constraint matrix actually can't be unimodular due to the presence of $M$ which is some arbitrarily large number. But the LP-relaxation constantly spits out integer feasible solutions, which for smaller graphs actually correspond to known optima and for larger graphs seems to check out as well.

edit: After examining the problem closer, I found that

a) the formulation is indeed correct

b) the linear relaxation consistently provides integer solutions with respect to x and y, but NOT b. It seems as though the b:s are basically conspiring to turn the problem totally unimodular. Setting $M = 10000$, b would constantly set itself to 0.99999 to minimize slack. This makes the x and y variables ONLY take on binary values. This is maybe obvious to experts but I found it extremely surprising. I have yet to see a case where it doesn't find the actual optimum, but this is probably due to a lacking setup of example graphs.

Comment: I have not proof-read the question, but I have a general comment. If the problem is NP-complete, it is "extremely unlikely" that we have found a polynomial time algorithm to solve it. Sometimes a problem might have a seemingly efficient formulation (such as a linear program), but the complexity can still blow up due to the *number* of constraints (or variables), or the complexity required to form the constraints.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I don't believe I have proven P=NP :)

Comment: But it still seems as if the number of constraints grows as O(n^4)...

Comment: Typo in 2nd constraint. Also, 6th constraint, what is $k$ on the right hand side? (The constraint is repeated only for $i,j$. What is $M$?

Comment: Cross-posted on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184965/14578.  Please don't cross-post, as it violates site rules.  For the future: well, you weren't actually recommended to cross-post: saying that a question might be better elsewhere isn't an invitation/suggestion to cross-post, though I realize that could be confusing or unclear, especially to new users.

Comment: What are the ranges of $i$ and $j$? What is $n$; the number of nodes as usual?

Comment: The sixth constraint is the connectivity constraint. It says there is a path of exactly length n from i to j if there is a path of length n-1 from i to k and a path from k to j. So k ranges over all nodes. M is some huge number. Basically, the constraint says "$y_{ij}^n = 1$ iff $\exists k:y_{ik}^{n-1} + x_{kj} = 2$"

Comment: n = number of nodes, i,j,k,n all range from 1 to $N = $ number of nodes

Comment: Can you please edit your question to correct the typo in the second constraint, and add the necessary details? Is it $N$ or $n$ that is the number of vertices? It should be $N$ given the system, but your previous comment is confusing.

Comment: I have made some very odd discoveries. The model is correct. The LP gives integer solutions, sort of. I will update shortly.